# Android: file not found using android-pdfviewer

Tags: android, pdf-viewer

I integrated Pdfviewer.jar taken from http://andpdf.sourceforge.net/ into my application. I am trying to view a pdf file located in the raw folder. However it is showing as "file 'android.resource://com.example.pdf/raw/demo.pdf' not found": the following is my code snippet:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyPdfActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(PdfViewerActivity.EXTRA_PDFFILENAME, "android.resource://com.example.pdf/raw/demo.pdf");
        startActivity(intent);
```

Could any of you tell me whats wrong and whats the correct path to be given?